# Как получить нужное значение из ListView с учетом фильтра (Java Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я выдергиваю значения из ListView 
и когда фильтр не используется то все хорошо . Но если используется то вместо нужного числа на позиции 2 с учетом фильтра я должен получить 0.306677 а получаю 10,361.98 (Ниже фото) . Получается что он выдает значение как бы по позиции без  фильтра а нужно с учетом фильтра .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                int count = lv.getCount();

                if (count > 1)

                {


                    EditText Filter = (EditText) findViewById(search_Filter);
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("AppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("Filter", Filter.getText().toString());
                    editor.apply();


                    ////////////
                    EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(search_Filter);


                    theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                            (Main3Activity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                        }
                    });
                    ////////////


                    Filter.setText(settings.getString("Filter", ""));
                    Filter.setSelection(Filter.getText().length());


                    editor.remove("Filter");
                    editor.apply();


                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            // берём строку из списка по нажатой позиции
                            String row = titleList.get(i);
                            // находим первый $
                            int start = row.indexOf("$");
                            if (start == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // находим второй $
                            int end = row.indexOf("$", start + 1);
                            if (end == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                            // и присваиваем переменной
                            s = row.substring(start + 1, end);
                            s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");

                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Copied_activity3) + " " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // находим второй .

                            // находим первый .
                            int start1 = s.indexOf(".");
                            if (start1 == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // находим второй .
                            int end1 = s.indexOf(".", start1 + 1);
                            if (end1 == -1) { // если не нашли
                                // Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                            // вырезаем кусок из строки по найденным позициям
                            // и присваиваем переменной
                            s = s.substring(0, end1);
                            Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.Copied_activity3) + " " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if (end1 == -1) { // если не нашли
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Not have data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: `String row = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);` - нужно взять строку не из полной коллекции, а из адаптера, где список отфильтрован. Это через вью, а можно напрямую `String row = adapter.getItem(i);` - если ссылка на него доступна в этом месте кода.

Comment: Спасибо работает. Счастья  вам  любви и успехов вы просто сэкономили миллиард  моего времени